# Is it possible to create custom MessageBox Icons?

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

Is there anyway to create a custom `MessageBoxIcon`, like  `MessageBoxIcon.Warning` or something, only of my own image?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows message box is a sufficient means to display messages to the user. 
Try this link,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17253/A-Custom-Message-Box